# Отличие в смыслах

Tags: грамотная-речь

> "Те, кто не ценит жизнь - не достойны самой жизни"
>   "Те, кто не ценит жизнь - не достойны её"

Здравствуйте! Скажите, есть ли смысловая разница между двумя вышенаписанными предложениями?

Comment: Надо не тире, а вторую запятую поставить.

Comment: Не вторую запятую, а оба знака: и запятую, и тире.

Comment: А есть ли разница между предложениями? Хотя бы маюсенькая? Нет?

Comment: Смысловой разницы нет: в обоих случаях высказывание цинично и означает "... заслуживают смерти". Первый вариант конкретнее тем, что устраняет остатки возможных сомнений в высказанном смысле.

Comment: Первое предложение звучит точнее, но смысловая разница — никакая.